# Mailchimp Media Queries not working

Tags: email, mailchimp

Okay i am a little confused here. I am trying to send a test email of my html email i have to gmail, but my media queries are not taking effect. I am targeting screen as shown in tutorials.

i have my media queries setup like:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1050px) { DO STUFF }
```

Additionally i have tried to add google fonts to the email but they dont show, i have linked them in the head:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

is there a method to target available width of space inside email? Gmail opens emails up in a smaller window right, so i need to target that?

Answer (score 1):

Gmail does not currently support media queries.

[http://kb.mailchimp.com/mobile/campaign-behavior-on-mobile?_ga=1.60711151.37688562.1434776314](https://mailchimp.com/help/campaign-behavior-on-mobile/?_ga=1.60711151.37688562.1434776314)

Gmail does not support Google web fonts either.

[http://templates.mailchimp.com/design/typography/](https://templates.mailchimp.com/design/typography/)

One option, if you absolutely needed the font, would be to implement
the typography as an image. This is not ideal, but works.